# Problem with dual booting Arch and windows (using syslinux)

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, boot-loader, syslinux

I am trying to create a dual boot system.
First I installed windows 8.1
Then I installed in a separate partition arch linux.
Then I installed with the help of a guy in a greek forum syslinux giving the following commands :

```
pacman -S syslinux
syslinux-install_update -iam
```

Then I am trying to edit properly the `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg`

```
Label arch
   MENU LABEL Arch Linux
   LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux
   APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
   INITRD ../initramfs-linux.img

Label archfallback
   MENU LABEL Arch Linux Fallback
   LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux
   APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
   INITRD ../initramfs-linux-fallback.img


Label windows
    MENU LABEL Windows
    APPEND hd0 1
```

The problem is that the windows do not load when I select them from the menu.
Arch linux is working fine.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Try [Chainloading Windows](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Comboot/chain.c32)

Comment: Can you type an example?Thank you.

Comment: Would you please Bot into Arch, and post the output of `gdisk -l`

Comment: I fixed that.The correct settings are COM32 chain.c32 and the next line is APPEND hd0 1

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: Now everything is working fine except from windows 8.1 shutdown!Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed that by turning off windows 8 fast shutdown.

Answer (score -2):

When you say windows does not load youre not being real specific. Syslinux is more manually set and can be picky. You might want to install grub instead and run os-prober. Easier for the newer user. You might have a problem where the windows repair disk or install disk needs to repair something as Windows can be very finicky especially where its file system is involved.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. And syslinux is, arguably, a lot less "picky" than Grub.

Comment: Well thats arbitrary Jason. Grub is a pain if you try to manipulate it manually. But I dunno they both work. Syslinux is fine but for nooBs? I dunno....you tell him.

Comment: They [have already been told](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157303/problem-with-dual-booting-arch-and-windows-using-syslinux/157388?noredirect=1#comment257477_157303)...

Comment: Wotever! I hope youre happy voting me down. I'm sure you are.